# Node.js API response to different Recipient

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api

My [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) API get triggerd from **xyz** source and I want to send this API's response to **pqr** target.

I don't know how to solve this problem. Is there any possible way to send response to other than who triggers the API ?

Comment: you can try socket for this case, I think

Comment: If you want bidirectional communication, you're either going to need **pqr** to poll the API, or use something like [socket.io](https://socket.io)

Comment: at recipient side fron-end developer haven't implemented anything related to socket, So I can't go wih that option.

Comment: **1.** Use WebSockets if _pqr_ is using browser **2.** If _pqr_ is another server, it could expose an endpoint that you API could send response to. Unfortunate that you don't give any details about "sources".

Comment: Can you provide more info about what kind of API you're exposing? Is it HTTP (REST, SOAP) or something else?

Comment: the pqr domain should listen to an endpoint (either http or socket) where your xyz domain will send a response when it receives a request. If pqr is abrowser page then either uit should poll the xyz domain for a response or better use websockets for bidi communication

Comment: These are REST APIs